# Trim String - get only what I want

Tags: java, string, char, trim

I need to trim a given code in Java after the first whitespace.
ex. if i have a String (call it `inputstartString`) with the value

```
1 100 2 34
```

I need to get the second number (number 100 in this case)
I thought this would go with a trim, but i have absolutely no clue how to do it in this case,
afterward I need to do it for the following numbers as well, but I guess once I learn how it goes I can easily do it with the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim is used to remove trailing or leading whitespace characters. How about String#split()?

```
String[] elements = "1 2 3 4".split(" ");
```

This would create an array of 4 elements, each containing a single number.

Comment: yeah, but the dumm thing is, the numbers could also be
1 100 2 34
in which case i wouldn't get the 100

Comment: Have you actually tried it? `"1 100 2 34".split()[1]` is equal to `"100"`.